# Sparql query with optional and filter

Tags: sparql

I wrote sparql query where if I bind a variable ($company_parameter = XXX) the result is all documents that belongs to a person inside company XXX;if instead I execute the query without bindings it will return all the documents in my database (even those of the people that do not work in any company).

The query is this, where I add or not a line like
`BIND(XXX as ?company_parameter) .` depending on the result I want:

```
SELECT 
  ?doc
  ?person
  ?company_label
 WHERE { 
  ?doc rdf:type  <document> . 
  OPTIONAL { 
    ?doc <belongsTo> ?person . 
    OPTIONAL { 
       ?person <worksin> ?company . 
       ?company rdf:type  <company> . 
       ?company rdfs:label ?company_label .
    } 
  }
  FILTER (!BOUND($company_parameter) || $company_parameter = ?company) .
}
```

The query works fine when I do not specify the BIND, but
a problem arise when I specify the BIND, as the result contains all the records with the specified company plus some, but not all, records without a company.

Is this something that should happen?
Should I always add to the filter a check like `BOUND(?company)` before comparing the parameter?

Comment: why can't you just do `BIND(XXX as ?company)` and remove the `FILTER`? Or even better resp. more generic, use `VALUES ?company {XXX}` and put it at the beginning: `SELECT 
  ?doc
  ?person
  ?company_label
 WHERE { VALUES ?company {XXX}
  ?doc rdf:type  <document> . 
  OPTIONAL { 
    ?doc <belongsTo> ?person . 
    OPTIONAL { 
       ?person <worksin> ?company . 
       ?company rdf:type  <company> . 
       ?company rdfs:label ?company_label .
    } 
  }}`

Comment: I cannot use only the BIND without the filter, since the company part is inside an optional, doing like that will extract all the records. Same with the VALUES.

Also I am somewhat restrained that this query is generated by an editor and executed not directly, so I cannot change it depending whether it should work with the parameter filled in or not, it should work in both cases.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm finding similar strange behavior with GrapDB, whereas Fuseki behaves like expected. In a situation with an optional clause within another optional clause, combined with a filter and a bind.